# How to back-up or copy a world

Tags: ps3, terraria-console

In terraria on ps3 Its telling me there is a save game game but It doesn't show the worlds
Individualy so if I copied the saved data it doesn't work it would replace the character's
and worlds in all so is there a way to only access and copy 1 world

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a USB

**Saving:**

1) Put USB in PS3.

2) Goto Game tab.

3) Goto Save Data Utility (PS3) Tab.

4) Look for save.

4.B) If save not found, look for it in the Game Data Utility Tab.

5) Press Triangle on controller and select copy.

6) Select your USB and let it copy over.

7) Done! Your save is now on your USB which can be used as a backup or put on another PS3.

**Loading:**

1) Go again, to Game, Save Data Utility.

2) Select your USB.

3) Locate save.

4) Press triangle and select copy.

5) Locate and save to PS3.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of backing up a singular world is to upload the world to the cloud before deleting it. When you redownload it, be sure to upload the world you are about to replace in order to keep that safe too. Make sure you name your worlds too so that it's easy to tell which one is which when redownloading. I don't reccomend the USB option because it has corrupted some of my worlds in the past. Even though you are restricted to 24 worlds in the cloud, it's a safer option to the USB and is a lot quicker. :)